# How to iterate through for loop in reverse in Jade?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, pug

```
ul.blogpostGrid
for child in page.get('/posts').children
    a(href=child.url): li.col.span_1_of_4 
        h2 #{child.title}
        div.imgThumb(style='background-image: url(#{child.url}thumb.jpg);')
        p #{child.excerpt}
```

The For Loop currently displays the blogposts in ascending order of creation. How can I reverse the order of displaying them?
Is there a reverse function? If yes, how can it be implemented in this context?
I'm using woods cms. https://github.com/studiomoniker/woods

Comment: Use javascript (can be done in Jade files) to obtain the list of posts and reverse it, then use jade to iterate the reversed list.

Answer (score 2):

This helped.

```
for child in page.get('/posts').children.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [while](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/) to iterate over the posts backwards:

```
ul.blogpostGrid
- var posts = page.get('/posts').children;
- var postIndex = posts.length;
while postIndex >= 0
    a(href=posts[postIndex--]): li.col.span_1_of_4 
        h2 #{posts[postIndex--].title}
        div.imgThumb(style='background-image: url(#{posts[postIndex--].url}thumb.jpg);')
        p #{posts[postIndex--].excerpt}
```